# train data must be floating-point matrix in function cvCheckTrainData runtime error

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi my training data contains numbers of type long double`(like 1.6448e-43, -6.08498e-36)`. which OpenCV datatype should i use in the following code:

```
Mat training_data = Mat(NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_SAMPLES,
                ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE, *HERE*);
```

When I am using the following data type it is giving me the above said runtime error:

```
Mat training_data = Mat(NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_SAMPLES,
                ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE, CV_64FC1);
```

While using the open cv random forest, i.e CVTrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data need a `double` type, so the correct type for the `Mat` should be CV_64F (it is the same than CV_64FC1). However, some OpenCV functions cannot handle any type of data, and they may expect just a certain one. In your case, the `cvCheckTrainData` function may expect data with type CV_32F, that is a `Mat` of `float`'s. Try it, but in that case, your data would lose some precision.

Comment: Hi. I am using open cv random forests cvTrees. is it possible to use CV_64F for that?

Comment: Do you mean CvRTrees? According to the documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html?highlight=random%20forest#cvrtrees-train), the ::train function requires CV_32F, that is float data.